# Non-symmetric core load when playing a game

Tags: ati, games, performance, cpu

I play Serious Sam 3 on Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 with AMD Phenom II X4 955 processor. And all time I play it there was fully loaded only one core. Command

> mpstat 1 1500 -P ALL

after some time gives summary about idle-time percentage for each CPU:

> CPU0 = 12.86%; CPU1 = 77.04%; CPU2 = 85.36%; CPU3 = 82.47%

Obviously, CPU0 was loaded more time. I repeat the test, and get nearly the same result

> CPU0 = 13.73%; CPU1 = 80.37%; CPU2 = 85.72%; CPU3 = 83.10%

Any time I minimize game and look to CPU-load widget in KDE I see that CPU0 fully loaded.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I get the Sam3 process PID and then executed

> taskset -p 7160
>
> pid 7160's current affinity mask: 1

Another question why that was done. This question to «Steam» & game developers…
Not fault of «Ubuntu».